# Flutter drawer closes on theme change. How can I prevent this?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation-drawer, bloc

I am toggling application theme inside `Scaffold` drawer. Whenever I switch themes drawer immediately closes. Is there any way to keep drawer form closing on parent rebuild due to theme change?

```js
 return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          const DrawerHeader(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0x4D4971FF)),
            //https://gist.github.com/lopspower/03fb1cc0ac9f32ef38f4
            child: Text(
              'Header',
              style: style,
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: const Icon(Icons.brush),
            title: const Text(
              'Dark Mode',
              style: style,
            ),
            trailing: Switch(
              value: context.read<ThemeModeCubit>().state == ThemeMode.dark,
              onChanged: (value) {
                context.read<ThemeModeCubit>().toggleBrightness();
              },
            ),
          ),
       ]
      ),
   );
```

Here is the Builder that uses Cubit.
StackOverflow says

> It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more
> details.

```
class AppView extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
        builder: (context, authState) {
          final _router = AppRouter(
            status: authState.status,
            initialMessage: null,
          ).router;
          return MaterialApp.router(
            
            themeMode: context.watch<ThemeModeCubit>().state,
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            routerConfig: _router,
          );
        },
     
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the Cubit

```
class ThemeModeCubit extends HydratedCubit<ThemeMode> {
  ThemeModeCubit() : super(ThemeMode.system);

  void toggleBrightness() {
    emit(state == ThemeMode.light ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light);
  }

  @override
  ThemeMode? fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ThemeMode.values[json['themeMode'] as int];
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic>? toJson(ThemeMode state) {
    return <String, int>{'themeMode': state.index};
  }
}
```

> **UPDATE**

```
class AppView extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _router = AppRouter(
      status: context.watch<AuthenticationBloc>().state.status,
      initialMessage: null,
    ).router;
    return MaterialApp.router(
        theme: AppTheme.of(context).light(),
        darkTheme: AppTheme.of(context).dark(),
        themeMode: context.watch<ThemeModeCubit>().state,
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        routerConfig: _router,
      );
   
  
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please produce reproducible code on ThemeModeCubit and Dart/Light Theme in your app

Comment: Is this drawer inside BlocBuilder ? or normal Builder ?

Comment: its inside bloc builder. I updated my snippets

Comment: Remove your `BlocBuilder` and use `BlocProvider` to provide the bloc, see my edited answer for more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing this because `BlocBuilder` builds every time the `state` changes, the moment you change the state to `light` the state is changed , the whole `Widget` under the `BlocBuilder` is rebuild.

##### What is the best way to handle this ?

To use `buildWhen` prop of the `BlocBuilder`. Here try specifying your condition and exclude the condition where your state changes from light to dark or vice-versa

##### Code Structure:

```
BlocBuilder<BlocA, BlocAState>(
  buildWhen: (previous, current) {
    // return true/false to determine whether or not
    // to rebuild the widget with state
  },
  builder: (context, state) {
    // return widget here based on BlocA's state
  }
)
```

##### Alternatively

Remove the BlocBuilder as a whole as you are changing just the state to toggle `colorTheme`. `Drawer's` scope should be outside the scope of `BlocBuilder` if you are not using `buildWhen` to prevent drawer from re-rendering

---

##### Suggestions

1. Foremost, your Code architecture needs fine tuning because `BlocBuilder` is introduced to build only the required widget at time of neccessary.
2. Wrapping the whole `MaterialApp` inside `BlocBuilder` is heavily discouraged. And it shouldn't be used at all. Because for every state change, your complete app is rebuilding.

```
BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
        builder: (context, authState) {
          final _router = AppRouter(
            status: authState.status,
            initialMessage: null,
          ).router;
          return MaterialApp.router(                         //❗ Highly Dicouraged
            themeMode: context.watch<ThemeModeCubit>().state,       
            routerConfig: _router,
          );
        },
     
    );
```

```
class CounterApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: BlocProvider(
        create: (_) => AuthenticationBloc(),   Just Create your Bloc here
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

3. Try to use `MultiBlocProvider` instead of nesting `BlocProvider`.

Comment: I tried buildWhen method. Drawer still closes on theme change.

Comment: Remove your MaterialApp wrapped inside the BlocBuilder.And find my edited post. Hope it gives you picture of bloc architecture.

Comment: Yes I am using `MultiBlocProvider`.
I removed `BlocBuuilder` instead I am using 
`themeMode: context.watch<ThemeModeCubit>().state,` inside `MaterialApp`.

Comment: please update the code in the question

Comment: What have you used inside `buildWhen` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250860/discussion-between-krishna-acharya-and-soliev).

Comment: Can you explain why creating blocs outside `MaterialApp` is discouraged?

Comment: You should create your bloc , more precisely provide your bloc on top of MaterialApp , I stated dont wrap your materialApp inside your BlocBuilder because it changes the build of entire app whenever the dependencies change

Answer (score 1):

Normally this doesn't suppose to do that. As Flutter only rerender the widget which are connected to changed value. Are you sure you are using the BlocBuilder in the right place?

Also check that in either BlocBuilder or inside the `toggleBrightness` method of the Cubit you are not updating any other state or value which is updating something else.

This can also happen if you are using `BlocListener` and setting some value inside the listen method of it like..

```
BlocListener<BlocA, BlocAState>(
  bloc: blocA,
  listener: (context, state) {
    // Check if you are updating some value inside this.
  }
)
```

You can test my sample code from this url https://dartpad.dev/?id=c79010cc6c1f27b0c1846191603e4dc9 and check if you have implemented the basic structure like this.

If this not solve your problem then you might have to update your question with more code sample & detail.

### **Updated after code**

Here you are changing the widgets when changing theme but inside that another builder for auth is creating a new router.

```
 return BlocBuilder<ThemeModeCubit, ThemeMode>(
      builder: (context, themeMode) {
        return AppTheme(
          child: BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
            builder: (context, authState) {
              final _router = AppRouter(
                status: authState.status,
                initialMessage: null,
              ).router;
              return MaterialApp.router(
                theme: AppTheme.of(context).light(),
                darkTheme: AppTheme.of(context).dark(),
                themeMode: themeMode,
                debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                routerConfig: _router,
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

Try switching it like this.

```
 return BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
      builder: (context, themeMode) {
        final _router = AppRouter(
        status: authState.status,
           initialMessage: null,
        ).router;
        return AppTheme(
          child: BlocBuilder<ThemeModeCubit, ThemeMode>(
            builder: (context, authState) {
              return MaterialApp.router(
                theme: AppTheme.of(context).light(),
                darkTheme: AppTheme.of(context).dark(),
                themeMode: themeMode,
                debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                routerConfig: _router,
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

Comment: I see  your demo and its working as expected. I don't have any other state except `themeMode` inside my cubit. I have no idea why it is not working in my case.